# Conditional clickbox in asp.net c# gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, conditional-statements

I am new to Asp.net and C#, but I need to help my boss to design some web form.
Below is my code to design a big web form for user to input account and click on the checkbox. How can I make people click on the first check box, then the second checkbox will also be selected?

Please let me know what kind of question will help you understand what I want to accomplish. Thank you!

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Service_Solution" %>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns> 
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <th colspan="30">Key Account Desk Service Solutions</th>
                <tr>
                <th style="width:0px"></th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
                <th colspan="4">Shipment Monitoring</th>
                <th colspan="2">Shipment Tracing</th>

                </tr>                   
           <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th class="auto-style8">Customer Name/Location</th>
                    <th class="auto-style8">Account Number</th>
                    <th class="auto-style8">100% Real Time Proactive Monitoring  through QCC and QSMS</th>
                    <th class="auto-style8">100% Proactive Monitoring through NPTS</th>


                </tr>             
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CB1" runat="server"  />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:CheckBox ID="CB2" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>    
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the event set in the markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CB1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CB1_CheckedChanged" />
```

You can use the NamingContainer property to make the connection between the two checkboxes:

```
protected void CB1_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb1 = sender as CheckBox;
    Control container = cb1.NamingContainer;
    CheckBox cb2 = container.FindControl("CB2") as CheckBox;
    cb2.Checked = cb1.Checked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the first checkbox:

```
OnCheckedChanged="Check_Clicked"/>
```

And the method:

```
void Check_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
     CB2.Checked = CB1.Checked;
}
```

Comment: Hi @the anathema. Thank you for your response.
I can't find CB1 and CB2 in my Check_Clicked, I only see Check_Clicked in my option.